# Issues handing over managedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have been reading up most questions on this item, but somehow I can't figure this one out.

I managed easily to hand over the ManagedObjectContext from the AppDelegate to the first view in previous applications I tried, where the initial viewController handled also the data.

Now in a new application I am building, I need an initial screen where the user needs to make a selection (through a few possible buttons).  On this screen my MOC is still intact as per my troubleshooting (the NSLog message gives me a valid address for the MOC).

Once the selection has been made, the app proceeds to a UIViewController with a TableView in it.  In this view I should be able to manage my data, but my MOC returns nil.

The app proceeds to the next view via a UINavigationController.

I incorporated following code in my AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
InitialViewController *controller = (InitialViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
return YES;
```

InitialViewController is the FIRST ViewController, where all is still fine.

The next viewcontroller is called MasterViewController and is the NSFetchedControllerDelegate.   Here I can't seem to get access to the NOC.  I have tried several approaches and solutions suggested in previous questions on the same topic, but none seem to work.

How can I with proper coding get the NOC to work in the MasterViewController?

Oh yeah, one of the solutions that worked is after the ViewDidLoad in the MasterViewController, I insert the following code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

My MOC is available now, but is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Storyboards,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueNameOfPresentingYourModalViewController"] == YES) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        YourCustomViewController *aController = (YourCustomViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        aController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueNameOfPushingYourViewController"] == YES) {
        YourCustomViewController *aController = segue.destinationViewController;
        aController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

If you are not using Storyboards, you similarly set your view controller's managedObjectContext where you are about to push or present it. Another common place is `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Why didn't I think of handing it over via a segue?  This looks like an elegant method without declaring a global variable...  I will try this out on my code later today and come back with my findings, but I have a feeling that this should work fine.

Comment: Tested an worked fine as expected.  Thanks for the input, often problems that look hard to overcome have a rather simple solution.

Answer (score -1):

You write "controller.managedObjectContext" so you clearly added a NSManagedObjectContext* property to InitialViewController.  You just need to add the same property to MasterViewController, and assign self.managedObjectContext to it as well.

If you don't want to have to add the moc to each controller, there is nothing wrong with simply declaring a global variable for your MOC:

In your appDelegate.h:

```
extern NSManagedObjectContext* moc;
```

Now any .m that has:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

will have access to the moc.  You can also just add a property to your appDelegate and then in each controller you can do:

```
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
app.managedObjectContext
```

Comment: It isn't good practice to have global variables that you access willy nilly. Much better off passing in the managed object context. I would suggest even an `initWithManagedObjectContext:` method and then saving the managed object context to an instance variable.

Comment: I was aware of your solutions, but they don't seem to be a good practise.  I need a solution where I only hand over the MOC on a view per view basis.  That way if in future project I want to work with bigger projects, I can declare a new MOC to temporary store data before writing it to the 'main MOC' (don't know if I am expressing myself clear here).  Anyway, thanks for the reply, but not really what I was looking for.